# Suggestion for English phrase dictionary?

Tags: phrases, dictionaries

I am not native English guy. One of the problem when I learn English is that I don't understand phrases, the phrase used cannot be found in the dictionary, which only contains single word.

> Examples:
>    - blow up
>    - carry on
>    - screw up

Sometimes I encounter such phrase which I don't understand and my dictionary doesn't have it. Do you know any such dictionary, standard online?

I just found an online one : http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:Main_Page

Would you please suggest more dictionaries?

Comment: No matter it is online, or a physical book which can be carried around, it is welcomed, especially those made of paper.

Answer (score 1):

Most dictionaries list the the meaning of phrases that use a word. Try [Oxford Dictionaries online](http://oxforddictionaries.com/).

For example, if you want to know what the phrasal verb [*blow up*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/search?searchType=dictionary&isWritersAndEditors=true&searchUri=All&q=blow+up&contentVersion=WORLD) means, search for it on this page. If you're not sure of the phrasal verb you want to use ("Is it *blow up*, *blow off*, *blow on*, or *blow into*?"), search for [*blow*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/blow?rskey=tNaelO&result=1), and then look for the phrases listed at the bottom of the page.

You can also try this for [*carry on*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/carry#m_en_gb0126280.068) and [*screw up*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/screw#m_en_gb0743740.050).

Answer (score 0):

try to google "phrasal verb"

here's a dictionary: http://www.englishpage.com/prepositions/phrasaldictionary.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you would actually like a phrase book, a book that has ready-made phrases in it, and you can carry it around. A suggestion would be something like [this](http://www.wordcentre.co.uk/phrasebookfree/index.html), but it costs.

Answer (score 0):

From [Idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idiom#External_links)'s external links at wikipedia article, the following

- [American Idiomatic Expressions](http://www.english-slang.com/eng/american/i_b/725-blow-up-in-ones-face)
- [The phrase finder](http://www.phrases.org.uk/bulletin_board/12/messages/532.html)
- [Dictionary of English Idioms & Idiomatic Expressions](http://www.usingenglish.com/reference/phrasal-verbs/blow+up.html)

yielded some results for a search on 'blow up'.